# Javascript forEach loop won't continue to next iteration

Tags: javascript, foreach

I am trying to do this challenge where the function should return the index value of the element when the sum of the values on either side of the element are equal. E.g. [1,2,3,4,3,2,1] should return 3, since on the other sides of '4' the values add to 6 (1+2+3) and (3+2+1). Also if there is no such value then the function should return -1.

```
function findEvenIndex(arr) {
  arr.forEach((element, index) => {
    let a = arr.splice(index + 1, arr.length); //array of values after current value
    let b = arr.splice(arr[0], index); //array of values before current value
    let suma = a.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => { //Sum of array of after values
      return accumulator + currentValue;
    }, 0);
    let sumb = b.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => { //Sum of array of before values
      return accumulator + currentValue;
    }, 0);
    if (suma === sumb) {  //comparing the two sums to check if they are equal
      return index;
    };
  });
};
```

My understanding was that if suma and sumb are NOT equal, then the next iteration of the forLoop will begin, however this does not happen and I cannot see why.

The function should return -1 if no such value exists, I haven't implemented this part of the code currently.

Thanks

Comment: `Array.prototype.splice` mutates an array in place: you should copy the array before mutating it. Mutating arrays in foreach callback is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Also, where exactly are you expecting to get the return value of `return index`? `forEach` doesn't use the return value in any way, and it always returns `undefined`.

Comment: your return index statement only exits the foreach iteration. Nothing returns from findIndex

Comment: @TedBrownlow - I know, but that will only be the case if the condition is true, I want it to to exit the loop but only if the condition is true. In this case, it is exits without the condition being met, and in that case it should not exit the loop but go to the next iteration.

Comment: You can't exit from a `forEach` loop, the array is always iterated through. `return` breaks just the current round, but it doesn't prevent the next round to come.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues to your code:

1. As I have pointed out in my comment, `Array.prototype.slice` mutates/changes the array *in place*, which is a bad idea when you are also iterating through the array at the same time. Therefore, make a shallow copy of the array before splicing it, by using the spread operator, i.e. `[...arr].splice()`
2. You are returning from a foreach function, but not returning from the outer `findEvenIndex()` function.

A better solution is to simply use a `for` loop: once an index is found, we can use `break` to short-circuit and break out of the loop since we do not want to perform further analysis. We store the index in a variable outside of the `for` loop, and return it:

```js
function findEvenIndex(arr) {
  let foundIndex = -1;
  
  for(let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {
    const a = [...arr].splice(index + 1, arr.length); //array of values after current value
    const b = [...arr].splice(0, index); //array of values before current value
    
    const suma = a.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => { //Sum of array of after values
      return accumulator + currentValue;
    }, 0);
    const sumb = b.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => { //Sum of array of before values
      return accumulator + currentValue;
    }, 0);
    
    if (suma === sumb) {  //comparing the two sums to check if they are equal
      foundIndex = index;
      break;
    };
  };
  
  return foundIndex;
};

console.log(findEvenIndex([1,2,3,4,3,2,1]));
```

Comment: If you're converting to a normal for loop then there's no reason to use break; you can return directly to the top function

Comment: @Terry - Thank you so much.. that makes a lot of sense.. One question though, how does the correct index value get returned, i.e. where does the foundIndex value get reassigned, I don't see where you have done that. In the if statement, you are only comparing the two and breaking the loop if the condition is true, but not assigning the current index value to foundIndex?

Comment: @SyedAbdullahAli It's done on this line: `foundIndex = index;`, right before the `break` statement

Answer (score 2):

you should use slice method instead of splice and return index out of loop

```
function findEvenIndex(arr) {
  
  var result =  -1;
  arr.forEach((element, index) => {
    let a = arr.slice(index + 1);  
    let b = arr.slice(0, index);  
    let suma = a.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
      //Sum of array of after values
      return accumulator + currentValue;
    }, 0);
    let sumb = b.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
      //Sum of array of before values
      return accumulator + currentValue;
    }, 0);
    if (suma === sumb) {
      //comparing the two sums to check if they are equal
        result =   index;
    }
  });
  return result;
}
```

also you can do it  using findIndex method

```js
const sum  = (a,b)=> a+b;
const findEvenIndex = (TestArr) =>
  TestArr.findIndex(
    (_, i) =>
      TestArr.slice(0, i).reduce(sum, 0) === TestArr.slice(i + 1).reduce(sum, 0)
  ); ;
```

Answer (score 1):

A few notes. Take advantage of the built in `.findIndex()`. Use `slice`, as it returns an altered copy of the array. `slice`/`splice` take indices as arguments, so do not use `arr[0]` in these methods.

```
function findEvenIndex(arr) {
  return arr.findIndex((element, index) => {
    let a = arr.slice(index + 1); //array of values after current value
    let b = arr.slice(0, index); //array of values before current value
    let suma = a.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => { //Sum of array of after values
      return accumulator + currentValue;
    }, 0);
    let sumb = b.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => { //Sum of array of before values
      return accumulator + currentValue;
    }, 0);
    return suma===sumb;
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a fast approach without changing the array and use two indices and a variable for the actual `delta` which is build by adding left side values and subtracting right side values.

If the indices are not in order exit the loop.

Then check `delta`. If `delta` is zero return left index or `-1` for not found separating index.

```js
function getIndex(array) {
    let delta = 0,
        i = 0,
        j = array.length - 1;

    while (i < j) {    
        if (delta <= 0) {
            delta += array[i++];
            continue;
        }
        delta -= array[j--];
    }
    
    return delta ? -1 : i;
}

console.log(getIndex([1, 2])); // -1
console.log(getIndex([1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1])); // 3
console.log(getIndex([1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2])); // 4
```